# json to sql query coverter

Tags: mysql, sql, json

Hello this my json for creating sql query i using **sql-json-generator** node js
 my problem is when i using array like

machine_category_id:

```
  [ '6f898735-7c38-4d7b-b7c7-ad006970d16e',
    '72e297d2-7a8a-4e1c-89f9-63dee6a3af33' ]
```

when given sql query its covert to string is its possible to covert same format

```
{ 
'$update': 'machines',
'$set':
 { created_at: '2020-05-01T16:17:25.911Z',
    created_by: 1,
     deleted_at: '',
     fileuploadedId: [],
     frm21_submit: null,
     machine_category_id:
      [ '6f898735-7c38-4d7b-b7c7-ad006970d16e',
        '72e297d2-7a8a-4e1c-89f9-63dee6a3af33' ],
     demoIds: [ '1234' ],
     modeluploadedId: [],
     name: 'sdsadasdasdsad',
     status: 'ACTIVE',
     type: 'equipment',
     unique_id: 'MAC1587349845912',
     updated_at: '2020-05-04T10:19:03.651Z' },

  '$where': [ { 'meta().id': 'a3782c33-38ca-47ea-a8b7-2dd529a84bdd' } ] }
```

my SQLGenerator query

```
UPDATE `machines` SET `created_at` = '2020-05-01T16:17:25.911Z',`created_by` = '1',`deleted_at` = '',`fileuploadedId` = '',`frm21_submit` = 'null',`machine_category_id` = '6f898735-7c38-4d7b-b7c7-ad006970d16e,72e297d2-7a8a-4e1c-89f9-63dee6a3af33',`demoIds` = '1234',`modeluploadedId` = '',`name` = 'sdsadasdasdsad',`status` = 'ACTIVE',`type` = 'equipment',`unique_id` = 'MAC1587349845912',`updated_at` = '2020-05-04T10:19:03.651Z' WHERE meta().id = 'a3782c33-38ca-47ea-a8b7-2dd529
```

any one help me how covert sql as per json same format .

Answer (score 0):

machine_category_id:

var catArr = [ '6f898735-7c38-4d7b-b7c7-ad006970d16e',
    '72e297d2-7a8a-4e1c-89f9-63dee6a3af33' ]

when given sql query its covert to string is its possible to covert same format

yes convert to  same format please change to
 json.stringify(catArr);